# How do I eliminate leading zeroes from my time conversion function?

Tags: ruby, time, formatting, leading-zero

I'm using Rails 4.2.7.  I have this function for converting time in milliseconds to a readable string

```
  def time_formatted
    Time.at(time_in_ms/1000).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
```

My question is, if I have something less than an hour, the function returns “00:37:25” or if I have something less than 10 minutes, the function returns “00:07:52”.    How do I eliminate leading zeroes from my function?

Comment: Is `time_in_ms` a method or should it be an argument? If not, it's an uninitialized local variable, which will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you have

```
time = "00:37:25"
```

You can use regex to remove the leading zeroes

```
regex = /^(0*:?)*/
```

Then you can run `sub!`

```
str.sub!(regex, '') #=> 35:25
```

Comment: 0* at the end of the regex is superfluous

Comment: An edge case: `"00:00:00".sub /^(0*:?)*/, '' #=> ""`, but it should return `"0"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex pattern to remove the leading zeroes

```
def time_formatted
    Time.at(time_in_ms/1000).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S").sub(/^(0+:?)*/, '')
end
```

http://rubular.com/r/NbSnQE9wDu

Comment: NOr does it work if time_in_ms = 60000 (1 minute).  The output is "01:00"

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    \A      # match beginning of string
    (?:00:) # match string '00:' in a non-capture group
    *       # perform above non-capture group match zero or more times, greedily
    0?      # optionally match a zero
    \K      # discard all matches so far
    .+      # match rest of string
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

"00:00:00"[r] #=> "0" 
"00:00:01"[r] #=> "1" 
"00:00:21"[r] #=> "21" 
"00:02:11"[r] #=> "2:11" 
"00:12:11"[r] #=> "12:11" 
"02:13:14"[r] #=> "2:13:14" 
"12:13:14"[r] #=> "12:13:14"
```